# Automated posting between Twitter and Facebook

Tags: facebook, twitter

If I automate posting from Facebook to Twitter, and from Twitter to Facebook, will I end up in an infinite loop or are the apps intelligent enough to recognise an automated post and not start bouncing it back and forward?

I'd like to be able to post on either platform and have the message appear on both - sometimes the message is better suited to Twitter, but still appropriate for the Facebook audience and vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

Only one way to check.

- apps.facebook.com/twitter/
- facebook.com/twitter

1st path: Twitter to Facebook

[image: From Twitter]

[image: To Facebook]

2nd path: Facebook to Twitter

[image: From Facebook]

[image: To Twitter]

Final Answer: **No**

There is no infinite loop. This is an okay way to get automated posted working.

Answer (score 2):

A way would be to setup an [If This Then That](http://ifttt.com/) task such that presence of a hashtag will cross post it to either service. [This recipe](http://ifttt.com/recipes/7776) created by me does that - posts any tweet with hashtag `#fb` to facebook